# DVD Rip in 720p/1080p resolution

Tags: dvd, resolution, ripping, 1080p

I have seen ripped movies in `720p`/`1080p` resolution but the source of the movie is DVD. So it must be a upscaled (`720 x 480` to `1,280×720` or `1,920×1,080`) video I guess, Is there any 
advantage in ripping a DVD to HD video, over ripping it to  video  with its original resolution ?

Comment: This seems to be opinion seeking, against the [faq].  Can you reword as a technical question otherwise it will get closed.

Comment: I think your video player will do a decent job of converting to the resolution of your display. I wouldn't try to upconvert it, just keep the full uncompromised rip of the DVD.

Comment: This is not an answer. But, just go through this article: hometheater.about.com/od/hometheatervideobasics/qt/dvdvidupscale.htm

I think your video player software will do quite good job of upscaling. You wont need to rip it to higher resolution.

If you are gonna play on a DVD player, then above article will illustrate the situation quite good.

Comment: @Paul Thanks... Changed the question a bit, don't know whether it is adequate...

Comment: @Paul I believe this can be answered in technical terms — after all, it's asking about whether upscaling DVD video results in loss of (objective and subjective) quality, which is something you can measure, or where the tradeoff is between upscaling at encoding or playback side.

Comment: @slhck I agree - this is thanks to the edit, the original was a bit flakey!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your video player software will do quite good job of upscaling. You won't need to rip it to higher resolution.

I mean ripping it to higher resolution wont make much difference in quality because it basically just interpolates new pixels from existing pixels.

If you are gonna play on a DVD player hooked up to HDTV, then [this](http://hometheater.about.com/od/hometheatervideobasics/qt/dvdvidupscale.htm) article will illustrate the situation quite good including connectors to be used for best quality.